# Passing image objects as Function & Class Arguments

Tags: javascript, html, string, function, ecmascript-6

How do you pass an image as argument in a function/class or is this impossible and if it is how would I fix it? For example:

```
var tree = new Image();
tree.src = "img/statobj/tree.png"
function additem(dimage){
document.getElementById("myitems").rows[0].insertCell(0).innerHTML ='<div id="invetoryitem" >'+ this.dimage + '</div>'
console.log(dimage) //gets undefined
}
```

I've tried dimage.src and other methods but nothing I use seems to work :/

Comment: IIRC `function(dimage)` is invalid syntax

Comment: sorry, that was just an example, that's not my actual problem I'll just fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass it like you would any other, but to display it, use `appendChild` not `innerHTML`:

```js
var tree = new Image();
tree.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/eb/Ash_Tree_-_geograph.org.uk_-_590710.jpg/220px-Ash_Tree_-_geograph.org.uk_-_590710.jpg";
function showTree(dimage) {
  document.getElementById("div").appendChild(dimage);
  console.log(dimage);
}

showTree(tree);
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
```

If you do want to use `innerHTML`, make an `<img>` with the `src` being `dimage.src`:

```js
var tree = new Image();
tree.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/eb/Ash_Tree_-_geograph.org.uk_-_590710.jpg/220px-Ash_Tree_-_geograph.org.uk_-_590710.jpg";
function showTree(dimage) {
  document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = "<img src='" + dimage.src + "'>";
  console.log(dimage);
}

showTree(tree);
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to name the function and call it by passing the image as an argument. If you are using `innerHTML` you have to create the image tag and add the source of the image received to the function as argument

```js
var tree = new Image();
tree.src = "img/statobj/tree.png"
function a(dimage){
document.getElementById("myitems").innerHTML ='<div id="invetoryitem" ><img src="'+dimage.src+ '"></div>'
console.log(dimage) //gets undefined
}
a(tree);
```

```html
<body id="myitems"></body>
```